# StoredProcedure return Complex Type , Data Service, Entity FrameWork and WCF

Tags: odata

I have Entity Framework TaskTracker.edmx
There is StoredProcedure GetEmployees and used Complex type  to return the Data

**at TaskTrackerDataService.cs**

```
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
{
  // Grant only the rights needed to support the client application.
  config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
  config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
  config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
}

[WebGet, WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
public IQueryable<TaskTracker_EDM.EmployeeView> GetEmployees()
{
  TaskTracker_EDM.TaskTrackerEntities ctx = new TaskTracker_EDM.TaskTrackerEntities();
  return  ctx.GetEmployees(string.Empty).AsQueryable();
}
```

**at Client Site [Console Application]**

```
      var emps = ctxDSvc.Execute<EmployeeView>(new   Uri("http://localhost:2402/TaskTrackerDataService.svc/GetEmployees", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));


  foreach (EmployeeView e in emps)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ID: {0} - {1} ", e.EmployeeID, e.Name));
  }
```

foreach is not working, There is no data in emps.

always emps has

```
+       emps    {System.Data.Services.Client.QueryOperationResponse<TaskTrackerConsoleTest.TaskTrackerDataService.EmployeeView>}    
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TaskTrackerConsoleTest.TaskTrackerDataService.EmployeeView> {System.Data.Services.Client.QueryOperationResponse<TaskTrackerConsoleTest.TaskTrackerDataService.EmployeeView>}
```

I read that OData doesn't support Complex Type.[Did they fix it] or are there  another solution.

Some said, use a Xml to Linq kind of approach to get the complex types. [any help]

Any help or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Serialize the result [ObjectToString] at the Server before send it to the Client application

then Deserialize it.

If there are other ideas, please don't hesitate to tell me.

```
1- at TaskTracker_WCF1 -> TaskTrackerData.cs 
   //When StoredProcedure return Complex Type , Then you need to serialise it [Object To String] before send it to Client application

   //OData doesn't support Complex Type

[WebGet]
public String GetEmployees_SPreturnComplexType(String nameSearch)
{
  TaskTracker_EDM.TaskTrackerEntities ctx = new TaskTracker_EDM.TaskTrackerEntities();
     List<TaskTracker_EDM.EmployeeView> hiEmployeeView = (List<TaskTracker_EDM.EmployeeView>)ctx.GetEmployees("Keko88").ToList();

    //Serialize object to String
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(hiEmployeeView.GetType());

    using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
    {
      serializer.Serialize(writer,hiEmployeeView);

      return writer.ToString();
    }      
}
```

2- at Console application at program.cs

```
  TaskTrackerDataService.TaskTrackerEntities ctxDSvc = 
  new TaskTrackerDataService.TaskTrackerEntities(new Uri("http://localhost:2402/TaskTrackerDataService.svc"));
  //=======================================
  //2-1Call StoredProcedure return Complex Type
  String emps = ctxDSvc.Execute<String>(new Uri(ctxDSvc.BaseUri.ToString() + 
                                  "/GetEmployees_SPreturnComplexType", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)).Single();

  //2-2We need to Deserialize it before use it
  var reader = new StringReader(emps);
  var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<EmployeeView>));
  List<EmployeeView> instance = (List<EmployeeView>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
  //=======================================

  foreach (EmployeeView e in instance)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("ID: {0} - {1} ", e.EmployeeID, e.Name));
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
  //=======================================
```